# My Inventory does not save a new object, it just resets to the ones I initiated with

Tags: java, arrays, inventory

So I have an assignment of doing a little inventory for a car company, that saves a code, brand, model, year and prize for the cars, but when i try to run the program it works great, it asks what it needs to ask and everything, the issue is that it doesnt save the new cars that I type in with the addCar method (nuevoVehiculo()) and I have been trying to figure it out for about 3 hours but with no success, any help would be appreciated.

Also sorry that some of the stuff inside the code is in spanish, Im from a latinoamerican country so spanish is what we do it with, any questions about it i can translate if necessary.

```
package javaapplication32;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

/**
 *
 * @author Luis
 */
public class Rutinas {

    static Vehiculo loteVehiculos[] = new Vehiculo[5]; //Crea arreglo con objeto.
    static Venta laVenta[] = new Venta[10];

    public static void Inicializa() {

        loteVehiculos[0] = new Vehiculo(1, "Toyota", "Yaris", 2018, 21000);//Se llena el primer vehiculo en el arreglo para empezar la lista.
        loteVehiculos[1] = new Vehiculo(2, "Honda", "Civic", 2017, 18000);

        for (int k = 2; k < loteVehiculos.length; k++) {

            loteVehiculos[k] = new Vehiculo();//Se crean los otros vehiculos sin informacion.
        }

    }//Fin Inicializa.



    public static int posicionVacia() {
        int indice = -1;
        for (int r = 0; r < loteVehiculos.length; r++) {
            if (loteVehiculos[r].codigo == 0) {
                indice = r;
                break;
            }
        }
        return indice;
    }//Fin Posicion Vacia.

    public static void nuevoVehiculo() { //Para llenar la informacion de los nuevos vehiculos.

        int posicion = posicionVacia();

        if (posicion > -1) {

            int codigo = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Digite el codigo del nuevo vehiculo."));
            String marca = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Digite la marca del nuevo vehiculo");
            String modelo = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Digite el modelo del nuevo vehiculo");
            int anio = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Digite el año del nuevo vehiculo"));
            float precio = Float.parseFloat(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Digite el precio del nuevo vehiculo en dolares"));

            loteVehiculos[posicion] = new Vehiculo(codigo, marca, modelo, anio, precio);
        } else {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "No hay espacio para un nuevo vehiculo");
        }

    }//Fin Nuevo Vehiculo.

    public static int buscaVehiculo(int codigo) {

        int indice = -1;
        for (int k = 0; k < loteVehiculos.length; k++) {
            if (loteVehiculos[k].codigo == codigo) {
                indice = k;
                break;
            }

        }

        return indice;

    }//Fin Busca Vehiculo.

    public static void eliminarVehiculo() {

        int vehiculo = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Digite el codigo del vehiculo que desea borrar."));
        int posicion = buscaVehiculo(vehiculo);

        if (posicion >= 0) {
            loteVehiculos[posicion].codigo = 0;
        } else {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "No se encuentra el vehiculo. ");
        }

    }//Fin Eliminar Vehiculo.

    public static void listaVehiculos() {

        for (int i = 0; i < loteVehiculos.length; i++) {

            if (loteVehiculos[i].codigo > 0) {
                System.out.println(loteVehiculos[i]);
            }
        }
    }//Fin Lista de Vehiculos.

    public static void InicioVentas() {

        laVenta[0] = new Venta(1, 12345, 1, "20 de Abril 2018", 15000);
        laVenta[1] = new Venta(4, 67890, 2, "10 de Abril 2018", 24000);

        for (int g = 2; g < laVenta.length; g++) {

            laVenta[g] = new Venta(); //Se crean las otras ventas.

        }
    }

    public static void agregarVenta() {

    }

    public static void menuVehiculos() {

        Rutinas.Inicializa();

        int n = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Digite \n1.Ingresar nuevo vehiculo. \n2.Lista actual de vehiculos. \n3.Eliminar vehiculo. \n4.Salir "));

        switch (n) {
            case 1:
                Rutinas.nuevoVehiculo();
                Rutinas.menuVehiculos();
                break;

            case 2:
                Rutinas.listaVehiculos();
                Rutinas.menuVehiculos();
                break;

            case 3:
                Rutinas.eliminarVehiculo();
                Rutinas.menuVehiculos();
                break;

            case 4:
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Gracias.");
                break;

        }

    }//Fin Menu.
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because every time you run method `menuVehiculos` it performs this: `Rutinas.Inicializa();`

To fix this you could call the initialization from another class. For example:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Rutinas.Inicializa();
        Rutinas.menuVehiculos();
    }

}
```

Then your method `menuVehiculos` does not need to do any initialization.

```
public static void menuVehiculos() {

        int n = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Digite \n1.Ingresar nuevo vehiculo. \n2.Lista actual de vehiculos. \n3.Eliminar vehiculo. \n4.Salir "));

        switch (n) {
            case 1:
                Rutinas.nuevoVehiculo();
                Rutinas.menuVehiculos();
                break;

            case 2:
                Rutinas.listaVehiculos();
                Rutinas.menuVehiculos();
                break;

            case 3:
                Rutinas.eliminarVehiculo();
                Rutinas.menuVehiculos();
                break;

            case 4:
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Gracias.");
                break;

        }

    }//Fin Menu.
```

Comment: I tried to delete `Rutinas.Inicializa()`off the menu, but it shows an error thats says `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException` after I type the code (codigo) of the new car.

Comment: Either don't use static variables and methods or use a static block to initialize the array. Another option is to have another class call a method to add the initial vehicles.

Comment: Sorry to bother this much, but what does using a static block to initialize the array means, Im quite new to programming as you can tell by the simplicity of my code, tho I tried taking off every static of the code, but it shows an error on the menu, that says `non-static method NameofMethod() cannot be referenced from a static content` even thought there isnt any static variables nor methods.

Comment: I realized after I wrote it that this may be a topic you're not familiar with. I added a fix that I think is simple and probably easier for you.

Comment: Thank you very much, it finally worked, such an easy fix up too, really appreciate the help.

Comment: @Flor you're quite welcome. I think you would benefit from reading some of the [Java Tutorials](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/) such as the lesson called [Classes and Objects](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/index.html)